# Github and git show different changes for a commit

Tags: git, github

I have a commit in a PR that I need to revert. [Github shows a ton of changes for the commit](https://github.com/HealthCatalyst/healthcareai-r/pull/1055/commits/fc44285b630a2152f41f000195ec8f76bca7658c), but git shows just a few. I cannot find the changes that Github shows---the ones I need to revert---locally. Github commit linked above; local changes below. What am I missing?!

```
$ git show --name-only fc44285b630a2152f41f000195ec8f76bca7658c
commit fc44285b630a2152f41f000195ec8f76bca7658c
Merge: b626839 1d24d68
Author: xxxx
Date:   Wed Apr 18 21:31:26 2018 -0400

    site updates

docs/dev/articles/site_only/healthcareai.html
docs/dev/articles/site_only/transitioning.html
docs/dev/index.html
docs/dev/reference/evaluate.html
docs/dev/reference/figures/README-plot_predictions-1.png
docs/dev/reference/machine_learn.html
docs/dev/reference/plot.predicted_df-2.png
docs/dev/reference/predict.model_list.html
docs/dev/reference/step_date_hcai.html
man/figures/README-plot_predictions-1.png
```

Comment: Have you used `git pull` to make sure your local is synced up with what is on github? What else have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commit `fc44285b630a2152f41f000195ec8f76bca7658c` is a *merge commit:* see the second line of output, which reads:

```
Merge: b626839 1d24d68
```

This means that commit `fc44285` (to abbreviate it) has *two* parents.

Git's command-line `git show` will, for such a commit, by default show a [*combined diff*](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html#_combined_diff_format).  The linked section of documentation describes the combined diff output format (which I find tricky to read), but fails to emphasize a key sentence that is hidden elsewhere in the documentation.  That key sentence is:

> Note that *combined diff* lists only files which were modified from all parents.

To make this sentence make sense, remember that each commit stores a *complete snapshot* of all files.  So, merge commit `fc44285` has a `docs/dev/articles/site_only/healthcareai.html` and a `man/figures/README-plot_predictions-1.png`, among all its many other files.  Parent #1, `b626839`, also has those files among all its many other files.  Parent #2, `1d24d68`, *also* has all those files.

Let's pick a file such as `README.md`—this is a total guess on my part, that file might not really exist—that is *the same* in all three commits.  It's not changed at all, so `git diff` between either parent and the merge would not show it.

Let's pick a second file—I'll make this one up too: `docs/README.txt`—that is the same in `fc44285` as in parent #1 `b626839`, but *different* in parent #2 `1d24d68`.  So `git diff b626839 fc44285 -- docs/README.txt` says nothing—the file is not changed—while `git diff 1d24d68 fc44285 -- docs/README.txt` shows us the difference between the files.

That means that `REMADE.md` is not modified from *any* parent, while `docs/README.txt` is modified from *one* but not *all* parents.

From your output we know that 10 files (if I counted correctly) are modified from *all* parents.  These are the combined diffs that `git show` would show, except that you said `--name-only`, so `git show` listed the ten files instead.

---

Meanwhile, GitHub shows something different.  That's because GitHub tries to hide from you what Git is really doing.  What GitHub actually shows is often totally impenetrable to me; I prefer to pick up everything from GitHub and view it with the command line, where it's obscure, but ultimately understandable.  This is one of those cases.  Use the command line.

Note that if you want a diff from one specific parent to the child, you can ask for just that:

```
git diff b626839 fc44285
```

for instance compares parent #1 (the main line commit you were on when you ran `git merge`, or had GitHub run `git merge`) to the merge result.

You can use `git show -m fc44285` to have Git run each of the two `git diff` commands that you need to show parent-#1-vs-child, followed by parent-#2-vs-child.

To reverse the effects of the merge, use `git revert -m 1`, but note that you cannot repeat the merge later:  The operation of merging depends on the history, and inserting an *undo the changes of a previous commit* commit does not *change* the existing history, it just adds a new ordinary commit whose change is *back out all the earlier changes*.  You can later revert the revert itself, i.e., *back out the backing out of the changes*.  This whole process tends to give everyone a headache, so be sure of what you are getting into.

Comment: What an excellent answer. Thank you. Turned out it was the changes from the second parent that needed to be reverted and `git show -m fc44285` made that obvious. My colleague must have gotten their merge backwards. Anyway, I learned a couple things about git in the process. Thanks.